# Scatter objects addon not working

Tags: add-on

I was following a tutorial on youtube and trying to make a city in Blender. I used the scatter object mod to scatter buildings around. It worked at first but then I am not happy with the result. So I deleted them and tried to redo them. But when I try to scatter the buildings again, I can't. I pressed f3 selected the scatter object option but when I draw, nothing happens. And when I press enter, an error message popped up. Please help.
Here are some photos:

When I selected the Scatter Object option and try to draw the objects:
[image]

When I pressed enter:
[image]

Here's a photo of my addon preference:
[image]

And here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\object_scatter\operator.py", line 81, in modal
    self.create_scatter_object()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\object_scatter\operator.py", line 130, in create_scatter_object
    self.get_all_matrices(), len(self.objects_to_scatter))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\object_scatter\operator.py", line 453, in make_random_chunks
    return make_chunks(sequence, chunk_amount)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\addons\object_scatter\operator.py", line 457, in make_chunks
    return [sequence[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(sequence), length)]
ValueError: range() arg 3 must not be zero

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and I realized I was a total moron. I didn't know you have to select the plane instead of those buildings when using the scatter object addon.